# my code doesnot work without refreshing. It doesnot show the correct color of page

Tags: javascript, css, oracle, oracle-apex

we created an oracle apex application about meeting room by using     javascript and css. when the room is full screen must be red hovewer it shows green if I dont refresh the page . How can I fix it? ı couldnt copy the all code but generally this code is for to put hours,day and put a color for the screen as green and red

```
(document).ready(function(){


var toggle = true;


function displayTime(){

var currentTime = new Date();

var hours = currentTime.getHours();
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds(); 
var meridiem = " ";

if(hours>11){
hours = hours;
meridiem = "";
}
if(hours === 0){
hours = 12;
}
if (hours<10){
hours = "0" + hours;
}
if (minutes<10){
minutes = "0" + minutes;
}
if (seconds<10){
seconds = "0" + seconds;
}
 ('#hours').text(hours);
 ('#minutes').text(minutes);
 ("#colon").css({ visibility: toggle?"visible":"hidden"});
}


function color(){

if(apex.item("P2_D_DUZENLEYEN").node.innerHTML != undefined){

document.body.style.background = "url(#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#red.jpg)";
}
else{
document.body.style.background = "url(#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#green-2.jpg)";
}


}
 color();
 displayTime();
 setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
 displayDay();
 displayDate();


  });
```

Comment: Not really enough code above.

Comment: `apex.item("P2_D_DUZENLEYEN").node.innerHTML != undefined` is probably false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to share other functions to understand what is going on, but for this code you should set interval for "color" function.

```
setInterval(color, 1000);
```

Comment: Hilal, you are calling "color" function just when page is loaded, if you call "color" function bottom of (last line) "displayTime" function, maybe it helps your problem.